# Proving that the number of atoms in a formula is equal to the number of the symbols $\land,\lor,\rightarrow$ plus 1

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

This is only correct for a formula only having the symbols $\land,\lor,\rightarrow$ .The proof behind this shouldn't be complicated but i'm having difficulty writing the induction step since I'm a novice with proofs by inductions.

I have started the proof like this: let $C(\varphi)$ be the number of occurences of the symbols $\land,\lor,\rightarrow$,and let $S(\varphi)$ be the number of atoms for a well formed formula $\varphi$.

**Base step**:$\varphi$ is an atom ,then $C(\varphi)=0,S(\varphi)=C(\varphi)+1=1.$

**Induction step**:Here i'm thinking of taking some $S(\varphi_1),S(\varphi_2)$ for a well formed formulas and then checking the 3 cases where i do $S(\varphi_3)=S(\varphi_1\lor\varphi_2) \implies S(\varphi_3)=S(\varphi_1)+S(\varphi_2)+1.$
similiary for $\land,\rightarrow...$

Is my induction step correct? if so i need a little help in writing it correctly to be considered a proper proof because i'm thinking that i'm failing to do that.

Comment: I removed the (induction) tag because this question is about structural induction and the tag is reserved for mathematical induction.

Comment: @GitGud You could certainly do an ugly induction on the number of connectives instead of a structural induction, but I suppose the desird form of proof is up to the OP

Comment: @MarkS. Certainly, but the OP's question suggests they are using structural induction, that's why I removed the tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is correct. You only need to notice that

$$ S(\varphi_3) = S(\varphi_1 \land \varphi_2) = S(\varphi_1) + S(\varphi_2) = C(\varphi_1) + 1 + C(\varphi_2) + 1 = C(\varphi_1)+ C(\varphi_2) + 2$$

and

$$ C(\varphi_3) = C(\varphi_1 \land \varphi_2) = C(\varphi_1) + C(\varphi_2) + 1$$

You don't really need to distinguish the $3$ cases as we are not really using the properties of the connectives.

Comment: How are you going to prove it for the negation without distinguishing it?

Comment: @Git Gud there is no negation case in the given formulas ,@Manlio It is then a sufficient proof?

Comment: @user3133165 - The base step in the OP is OK. Also Manlio's answer is OK for a formula of the form $\varphi = \varphi_1 \circ \varphi_2$ where $\circ \in \{\land, \lor, \to\}$. But in that answer the case where $\varphi = \lnot \varphi_1$ is missing! In this case, $S(\varphi) = S(\varphi_1) = C(\varphi_1) + 1 = C(\varphi) + 1$, where the second identity holds by induction hypothesis.

Comment: @user3133165 You're right, I missed that. I should say, however, that $\neg$ not being present is probably a fluke. Also it's unlikely that your version of structural induction doesn't require the negation.

Comment: @user3133165 Yes, to prove the claim I don't see anything needed on top what I wrote

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco The claim fails for $\lnot$ because if $\varphi$ is an atom then $S(\lnot \varphi) = C(\lnot \varphi)$

Comment: @GitGud The OP explicitly mentions only binary connectives. As I commented above, the claim fails for $\lnot$.

Comment: @Manlio - If $\varphi$ is an atomic formula, then $S(\lnot \varphi) = 1 = 0 + 1 = C(\varphi) + 1$, since $C$ doesn't count $\lnot$.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Yeah, well I thought that if you want to add $\lnot$ among the symbols you may also want to count it! I feel like we are kind of overkilling it right now (I bet there is an english way to say what in Italy sounds like "slicing a hair in four" :) ). To be honest, I did not consider the case of $\lnot$ simply because it was not in the OP. If you want to add it then we should probably underline whether we want to count it or not. In case we don't then your proof is obviously fine.